# Is all clarified butter/ghee made from different brands of butter having the same of flavor? Or not?

Tags: milk, butter, ghee

I know
the difference of the taste of many butter brands, but if you cook each of it into clarified butter. Does It still keep the difference of flavor/aroma/taste for each.

Comment: This feels like something you could test yourself.  Why not try it, with 3 different brands of butter?

Answer (score 1):

Clarifying butter entails the removal of most of the non-fat-soluble solids, which are responsible for much of the taste of butter (and the distinctiveness of different butters). In particular, “sharp” and “savory” flavors will be attenuated. However, flavor caused by breakdown or oxidation of the fat itself - what I’d call a “cheesy” character - will tend to remain.

Comment: Do you mean that almost clarified butter has the same taste/aroma?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Clarified butter tastes very different than butter, and two butters which taste very different from each other will tend to taste more similar once clarified.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. In my test, just some, not many brands of butter, much of clarified butter has similar in smell/taste as they were cool over 4 hours or some.